# Effect of area spring at slab on column

Tags: structural-engineering, springs, geotechnical-engineering, soil

Say that a simple building is supported by 4 columns , the column sitting on base slab. I assigned some sort of area spring to the base slab. When the area spring assigned is higher, this cause the compression of the column to be higher. I have 2 models, one showing the bending at beam/column junction is higher, another showing the bending moment at beam/column junction is lower. Which is correct? I am confused.

I think the hogging moment at beam/column junction shall be lower when the area spring at base slab is higher. This is because when the area spring is higher, compression on column is higher, this caused the column to be weaker, because of elastic shortening of column, higher compression force on column, column shorten more, the column is weaker. Hence, when column is weaker, it’s not able to support higher hogging moment at the beam-column junction.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please provide the two models, the loading, and the results that bother you. Your question is unclear and confusing.